# SugarCRM module installer is corrupting file on install

Tags: sugarcrm

I made custom module for SugarCRM and all is working fine, but I found that after using SugarCRM module loader to load my module, some files, which has many lines of code are corrupted after copying.

For example .js files with more than 3000 lines appeared only with 2600 lines.

I am looking for your advice! Thanks!

Comment: Corrupted or minified? Sugar has several mechanisms that minify CSS and JS files.

Comment: Large PHP files is corrupted too. And what to do with minified JS files (vendors)?

Comment: It seems that after setting larger `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` as well as SugarCRM config `upload_maxsize`, problem is gone.